# Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$mysqli_num_rows in

Tags: php

Here is my PHP code who is returning the following error.

```
public static function categoryParentChildTree($parent = 14, $spacing = '', $category_tree_array = '') {

    $db=Db::getConnection();

    if (!is_array($category_tree_array))
        $category_tree_array = array();

    $sql = 'SELECT id,name,parentid FROM category WHERE parentid = 14 ORDER BY id ASC';
    $resCategory=$db->query($sql);

    *if ($resCategory->num_rows > 0) {*
        while($rowCategories = $resCategory->fetch_assoc()) {
            $category_tree_array[] = array("id" => $rowCategories['id'], "name" => $spacing . $rowCategories['name']);
            $category_tree_array = Self::categoryParentChildTree($rowCategories['id'], '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$spacing . '-&nbsp;', $category_tree_array);
        }
    }

    return $category_tree_array;
}
```

please help me this function output this error

> Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$mysqli_num_rows in

Answer (score 0):

Your notice appears because the object is not created.

Replace line `$resCategory=$db->query($sql);` by this :

```
if($resCategory = $db->query($sql)) {
    //continue with your code...
    if ($resCategory->num_rows > 0) {
    ...
}

else {
    // SQL Query didn't return anything
}
```

Comment: $sql='SELECT id,name,parentid FROM category WHERE parentid = '.$parent.' ORDER BY id ASC';
    if($resCategory = $db->query($sql)) {
    //continue with your code...
    if ($resCategory->num_rows > 0) {